# p:commandButton breaks after prettyfaces integration

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have a xhtml-form, which should be submitted after clicking an `p:commanButton`. The button looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['formSubmit']}" ajax="false" action="#{quote.submit}" icon="ui-icon-check" />
```

After integrating `prettyfaces` this button doesn't work anymore. The method on the `Bean` named quote doesn't get invoked. I had a look to the html-output, but couldn't see any differences between before- and after prettyfaces-html. I also tested the same code when removing the specific pretty-faces-mapping. it works fine then ...

I use this for the prettyfaces url-mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="quote">
    <pattern value="/quote" />
    <view-id value="/sendQuote.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

I use:

- primefaces 5.2
- jsf 2.2 (mojarra)
- prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3
- tomcat 8.0
- ... I also tried with ReWrite 3.00 -> same result

any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: This is **not** a jsf `commandLink` but a PrimeFaces `commandButton`. Bad title. And jsf 2.2 is a spec version, not an implementation version.

Comment: Does it work with an `h:commandButton`?

Comment: no neither ... (I mentioned primefaces in the question-text - but doesn't seem to have to do something with this)

Comment: Could you try with PrettyFaces 2.0.12 and let us know the result? You can find instructions here: http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

Comment: no ... I tried also again with the plain jsf button.